# reading bash variable array into python via argparse

Tags: python-3.x, bash

I am trying to use argparse to read in a list of values from a bash script. But, it seems to only read 1 value rather than the list.

For example, in train.py

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='PyTorch ImageNet Training')
parser.add_argument('--lr', '--learning-rate', default=[0.1], type=float, nargs='+',
                        metavar='LR', help='initial learning rate', dest='lr')
args=parser.parse_args()
```

my bash script is as follows:

```
LR="1e-1 1e-2 1e-3 1e-4 1e-5 1e-6"
python train.py --lr=$LR
```

In train.py, print(args.lr) only outputs 1e-3. What is the correct way to read the list of values via argparse?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `=` from the argument, as follows:

```sh
python train.py --lr $LR
```

This will make `--lr` and each value from `$LR` into a separate argument for your python script.

Answer (score 0):

Put the entire argument in double-quotes, like this:

```
python train.py "--lr=$LR"
```

Should work on Windows, Linux, MacOS.